# firefox issues in reading onLayout with isotope

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, jquery-isotope

I run this:

```
$(".navMore li a").on("click", function(e) {

e.preventDefault();

var clicked = $(this);

$('.loadContent').css('visibility', "visible");

$('.loading').css('visibility', "visible");

    $(".nav li").removeClass("active");
    $(this).parent().addClass("active");     

url = this.href + " .content";
$newItems = $('<div></div>').css('visibility', 'hidden').fadeTo('fast', 0);
$newItems.load(url, function(){
    $('#main').prepend( $newItems).isotope( 'reloadItems' ).isotope({ sortBy: 'original-order', onLayout: fadeIt }); <== fadeIt is the function I am calling
    $(".fotorama").fotorama();
    Shadowbox.setup();
    clicked.removeAttr("href");
    $('.loadContent').css('visibility', "hidden");
    $(".fotorama-fullscreen").bind('click', function(){
        $this = $(this);
        $("#wrapper").fadeTo(1000, 0,function(){
            $("#main").isotope("destroy");
            $this.parent().find(".fotorama").trigger('fullscreenopen');
            $("#wrapper").fadeTo(1000, 1);
        });
    });
});
});
```

Then this:

```
function fadeIt() {
   alert("ciao");
   $("#main div").css("visibility", "visible").fadeTo(1000, 1);
}
```

Chrome is fine, code works and I get the alert while firefox ignore it completly. What Am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Removing `onLayout` and calling the function outside resolves it. Therefore I presume there must be some issues with [jquery isotope onLayout](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/docs/options.html#onlayout) and firefox